# codeigniter2 deploy on windows 10 with wamp server, memcached error fix

Tags: codeigniter, wamp, memcached, codeigniter-2, wampserver

I am trying to run the old codigniter2 website on windows 10 with a wamp server.

But I get the following error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Error
Message: Call to a member function get() on null
Filename: C:/wamp64/www/website.test/system/libraries/Cache/drivers/Cache_memcached.php:52
```

full error [image: img]

What should I do?

Comment: What version of WAMPServer? Also what version of PHP?

Comment: Did you install the Memcached Server

Comment: get() is a CI database function, if you get an error thrown by it then most likely the database setup is incompatible/wrong. Did your CI 2.x version work before? And if yes, with which php version?

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes, it's installed and runned, wamp php version 5.6.40, mysql version 5.7.31

Comment: @Vickel wamp server 3.2.3, CodeIgniter version is 2.2.6, it's work on ubuntu but never on windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem:

**Step 1 (enable Memcache in WAMPserver):**

- download the Memcache package that compatible with your PHP version
  and Wamp version (32 or 64 bits). I download the **Thread Safe** one.
- extract the downloaded package then copy the php_memcache.dll into
  your extensions folder of your PHP such as
  C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.40\ext. The php5.6.40 is your PHP folder.
- open the php.ini file and search for extension=php_bz2.dll which
  should be the first extension on the extensions list then copy
  **extension=php_memcache.dll** and paste at the end of the extensions
  list.
- restart Wamp server
- now you should see the Memcache loaded when you visit
  http://localhost

If the steps above don’t work, you just open the error log file at the logs folder at the root directory and check the error there.

**Step 2 (Changes in /system/libraries/Cache/drivers/Cache_memcached.php):**

Using this github [link](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/commit/9e8dc0e1b2175fc79b112d469626c76cc13610e3#system/libraries/Cache/drivers/Cache_memcached.php), i made changes in Cache_memcached.php:

Replace this:

```
$this->_memcached = new Memcached();
```

With this:

```
if (class_exists('Memcached')) {
      $this->_memcached = new Memcached();
   }
   else if (class_exists('Memcache')) {
       $this->_memcached = new Memcache();
   }
   else {
          log_message('error', 'Failed to create object for Memcached Cache; extension not loaded?');
          return FALSE;        
   }
```

And replace this:

```
if ( ! extension_loaded('memcached'))
```

With this:

```
if ( ! extension_loaded('memcached') && ! extension_loaded('memcache'))
```

Then delete (if exists):

```
$this->_memcached->setOption(Memcached::OPT_DISTRIBUTION, Memcached::DISTRIBUTION_CONSISTENT);
$this->_memcached->setOption(Memcached::OPT_LIBKETAMA_COMPATIBLE, true);
```

And this (if exists):

```
$this->_memcached->setOption(Memcached::OPT_PREFIX_KEY, $prefix);
```

**Step 3 (Refresh Database):**

- Delete and create new database
- import data (if big data you can import it via wamp server mysql
  console "use dbname; source c:/wamp64/www/dataname.sql")
- restart wamp server